# Aggregate Switch Case Syntax with Multiple Conditions

Tags: mongodb, switch-statement, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to do a simple switch case in Mongo, but keep getting syntax error messages

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { $project: {
    "age": 1,
    "Age Group":{
      $switch:{
        branches:[
          {
            case: {$lte:[{"age": "18"}]},
                    then: "Minor"
          },
          {
            case: {$gt:[{"age": "18"}]},
                  {$lte:[{"age": "30"}]},
            then: "Young Adult"
          }
        ],
        default: "No Age Group"
      }
    }
  }}        
])
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you actually have MongoDB 3.2, you need an [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/and/) for multiple conditions:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "age": 1,
    "Age Group": {
      "$switch": {
        "branches": [
          {
            "case": { "$lte": ["$age", "18"] },
            "then": "Minor"
          },
          // This one <----
          {
            "case": { 
              "$and": [
                { "$gt": ["$age", "18"] },
                { "$lte": ["$age", "30"] }
              ]
            },
            "then": "Young Adult"
          }
        ],
        "default": "No Age Group"
      }
    }
  }}        
])
```

In actual fact though, the way the branching actually works you do not need two conditions since the "first branch" short-circuits the following branches:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "age": 1,
    "Age Group": {
      "$switch": {
        "branches": [
          {
            "case": { "$lte": ["$age", "18"] },
            "then": "Minor"
          },
          // Just needs the $lte condition
          {
            "case": { "$lte": ["$age", "30"] },
            "then": "Young Adult"
          }
        ],
        "default": "No Age Group"
      }
    }
  }}        
])
```

Most importantly the [`$gt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/) and [`$lte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lte/) logical operators take "arrays" as an argument, and not an "object" as you tried to use them. This is different to the "query" operator form.

> **Note:** you also need to denote "field values" with `$`, otherwise it's just a "string". And of course the values of `age` are also strings, so `"9"` is not actually "less than" `"18"`. You probably should fix your data to store those as numeric values instead.

If you don't actually have MongoDB 3.2, then this was actually always achievable via [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/), but just a little longer in syntax:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "age": 1,
    "Age Group": {
      "$cond": {
        "if": { "$lte": ["$age", "18" ] },
        "then": "Minor",
        "else": {
          "if": { "$lte": ["$age", "30"] },
          "then": "Young Adult",
          "else": "No Age Group"
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

So that form of "nested" [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) is basically what [`$switch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/) does in a different syntax form, without the "nesting". But [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) has been around as long as the aggregation framework has been, so you always could do this.